# HTML VBA modification URL

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm trying to modify a link "`URL link`" using VBA Excel to extract specific Value from Site .

Below the Type of link :

URL`http://Confidential.eu.airbus.Confidential:Confidential/Confidential/consultation/preViewMP.do?mpId=XXXXXX`

What I want is to change `mpID=XXXXX` with `sheet("Feuil1").range("A1").value`but I didn't succeed , I don't have the right knowledge

So I don't have a clue how to manipulate this URL to open what I enter in `range("A1")` and look for specific line there and Copy and Past it in my excel File

Anyone could light me with some idea or help to better code this  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the string from `A1` using

```
Dim str As String: str = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A1").Value
```

Then create the URL from what you've stated

```
Dim myURL as String
' The & symbol concatenates strings. The _ symbol is for line continuation.
myURL = "http://Confidential.eu.airbus.Confidential:Confidential/Confidential/" _
        & "consultation/preViewMP.do?" & str
```